# What to do with this answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I recently flagged [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56742/8822) for moderator attention, because there are many problems with it, and that was my best idea about how to handle that.

The answer itself oversimplifies the question, contains some flawed calculations and implements a strategy which in certain cases just won't work. Not a big deal, we've seen other wrong answers on the site. Still it gets upvoted, as many readers are overlooking the problems with it.

You could say it should be edited to correct the calculation and address the problem in the strategy. However, that would make it identical with an 
other answer for the question (actually with my answer, but that's not why I'm posting this - I'm doing it not for authorship, but for quality).

So what options are left for us, regular users?
I've already
1) explained the problem in comments;
2) downvoted;
3) flagged for moderator attention - that was rejected because of 'Mods don't check for correctness of an answer'. That's understandable, but maybe they should actively help the site quality.

There is no possibility to flag it as 'low quality', maybe because it has a positive score. It kept getting scores even after I've added my concerns in comments.

Please advise what to do in such a case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in such a case you should

- explain the problem in comments
- downvote if you think the answer in question is bad enough to deserve it

(both of which you have done) and otherwise leave it alone. If another answer is better, then probably justice will eventually be done :-). This isn't a situation that calls for moderator intervention, I don't think.

Comment: See also: [How should blatant wrong answers be dealt with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160448/) (and the post it’s a dup of) which affirm that moderators don’t generally do quality control on answers (and why) - the most important thing one can do with bad or wrong answers is to **downvote** first, as once a bad answer is negatively scored, you can then **flag as Very Low Quality** which puts it in the review queue where the community can **Vote for, or Recommend, Deletion**. Enough “VLQ” flags *may* get Moderator action, but “this is wrong” will not (indeed MUST not).